# Travel to the US for 2 months as a non-resident Canadian

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens

I have been working hard for 5 years and I needed a mental break. I planned to vacation for 2 months in New York. I'm the type of person who needs a metropolitan life to feel functional. I won't be working during that time and I have cash in my residence country's account to pay for my time there. I also booked an Airbnb for the 2 months during my stay.

Will I have problems going to America? I never had issues before. I was born and raised in Southern Ontario and made trips in the past without problems. Are there any more documents I should bring?

- I have a Canadian passport.
- My work visa.
- A driver's license from my country of residence.
- A debit card from my country of residence.
- Some extra US cash.

Comment: What work visa? Why is it relevant here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Reading between the lines, I think the OP's "resident country" is somewhere other than Canada or the US, and a work visa is required for Canadians to work there.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes I work in an island nation and have a work visa there which will be stamped in my passport.  I am not worried about any of those details, I have all the necessary documentation with my travel bag at all times.

Answer (score 3):

As a Canadian, you can usually [visit the US for up to six months with no formalities required](https://ca.usembassy.gov/visas/do-i-need-a-visa/). For the purposes of immigration, "hanging out in New York City for two months and not working" counts as "visiting". There are exceptions for some people, such as those who have a criminal record.

The US CBP officer might ask you where you normally live, and if that's not Canada then you should state the truth. Your answer is unlikely to affect your admissibility into the US, unless your answer is Iran or North Korea or something like that.